# How do I implement a sprite-sheet in OpenGLES for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uikit, opengl-es, sprite, sprite-sheet

I am working from the GLSprite sample code example. What I want to know is what do I need to do to the code to have it treat my texture as a sprite-sheet? The only modification I have done so far is to create a 256 x 256 png of 16 smaller images to be my frames. I have never worked with sprite-sheets before. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the texture coordinates to map the required sprite. Texture coordinates are normally normalised (0 to 1). Assuming you have a 4x4 grid of sprites, the first sprite would have texture coords of...

```
0, 0
0, 0.25
0.25, 0.25
0.25, 0
```